TurtleBot2 Setup become difficult
According to Hardware Setup, the TurtleBot comes with a USB A-B cable and a USB splitter-type cable. I would like to know if I can buy the USB splitter-type cable from the market if I lose it.
Secondly, if I have not powered on the TurtleBot for a long time, can I power it on following the above tutorial, or do I need to take additional steps?
